# SQL Datatypes reccomendations

Tags: datatypes

I have these columns and their datatypes,
Could someone give me any advice whether they are right, and if not, suggest what is more appropriate?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: I have a friend in Brazil. His first name is `Jose Manuel Garcia Jesus Maria Piedro Gonzales` and his last name is `del Santo Christobel y Brazil`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_long_place_names

Comment: I'm not sure how we can decide on what datatypes are correct for your application, since we can't really determine your requirements based on the name you picked alone.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: I'm assuming that you are using SQL Server, from the type names listed, as you've not specified anything else.

2. You should allow for non-ANSI characters in names by using `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR` though of course to properly support extended character sets the rest of your stack might need work also...
3. You should allow for significantly longer names then 20 characters. Don't use `MAX` due to potential indexing and other performance concerns, as you are likely to want to search and/or sort by names.
4. You might need to extend the VAT number column a bit too, depending on the territories that you need to support. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAT_identification_number for a list of formats a number of which are longer then 11.
5. I would be inclined to widen phone number too.
6. Spaces, punctuation, and anything else that might require escaping, are a bed idea in column names. I would stick with letters, numbers, and underscore.

What is "client name" used for and how (if it does) does it related to the other name columns? There maybe specific advice about that depending on how it is intended to be used.